# What parameters or software is best to use to convert .MP4 to .FLV

Tags: ffmpeg, flv, mp4

I'm on Windows 7 and i have many .MP4 video that i want to convert on .flv. I have try ffmpeg and Free FLV converter, but each time the results are not what i'm looking for.

I want a video of same quality (or almost, looking good) and a more little size for the video, because right now, each time i have made a try, the video result is pretty bad and the video size just increase.

How can i have a good looking video, less in size and in .FLV ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Hi ! Yes i try ffmpeg and many command lines to find a good one, able to do the job like : `ffmpeg.exe -y -timelimit 60 -xerror -i mega.mp4 -qmin 2 -qmax 8 -ar 44100 mega2.flv`

Or just : `ffmpeg.exe mega.mp4 mega.flv` whitout a good result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, see slhck's blog post on superuser for a good [FFmpeg tutorial](http://blog.superuser.com/2012/02/24/ffmpeg-the-ultimate-video-and-audio-manipulation-tool/). FLV is a container format and can support several different video formats such as H.264 and audio formats such as AAC and MP3. The MP4 container can also support H.264 and AAC, so if your input uses these formats then you can simply "copy and paste" the video and audio from the mp4 to the flv. This will preserve the quality because there is no re-encoding. These two examples do the same thing, which is copying video and audio from the mp4 to the flv, but the ffmpeg syntax varies depending on your ffmpeg version. If one doesn't work then try the other:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c copy output.flv
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vcodec copy -acodec copy output.flv
```

However, you did not supply any information about your input, so these examples may not work for you. To reduce the file size you will need to re-encode. The link I provided shows how to do that. Pay special attention to the *Constant Rate Factor* section.

Comment: Hi !

Thanks a lot @LordNeckbeard ! I've learn many things in this tutorial and was able to convert my .mp4 video (H.264) to .FLV ! The size of my video was originally at 156mo and after the conversion 76.3mo ! (and the quality perfect !)

For that i've used `ffmpeg -i source.mp4 -c:v libx264 -crf 19 out.flv` and made several test to be sure and i am now !

I was never thinking ffmpeg was that powerfull ! Thanks again to you !